# Two plugins on same div causing conflict

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a slider and easyPaginate plugin to get slider with thumbnail navigation and pagination for those thumbnails. Only one plugin is working at a time. Tried hard to find it out but no luck. Also tried jQuery noconflict function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.snippet.min.js"></script>    
<script src="assets/scripts/slippry.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/main2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="slider">
<ul id="thumbnails" class="sy-box" >
 <li>
    <a href="#slide1">
        <img src="assets/images/background.jpg" alt="<h6>01.<span>History</span></h6><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in ante viverra, rutrum erat rutrum, consectetur mi. Proin at maximus est. Nullam purus ex, iaculis sed erat sed, blandit tincidunt quam. Cras scelerisque id quam sed dignissim Pellentesque urna nunc, gravida quis hendrerit ac, tristique ut quam. Vivamus suscipit dignissim tortor nec congue. </p>">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#slide2">
      <img src="assets/images/001.jpg"  alt="This is caption 2">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#slide3">
      <img src="assets/images/002.jpg" alt="And this is some very long caption for slide 3. Yes, really long.">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#slide4">
      <img src="assets/images/background.jpg" alt="And this is some very long caption for slide 4.">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="thumb-box">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="for_thmb">
        <ul class="thumbs" id="thumbs">
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#1" data-slide="1"><img src="assets/images/slider1.jpg" alt="This is caption 1 <a href='#link'>Even with links!</a>"></a></li>
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#2" data-slide="2"><img src="assets/images/slider1.jpg"  alt="This is caption 2"></a></li>
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#3" data-slide="3"><img src="assets/images/slider1.jpg" alt="And this is some very long caption for slide 3. Yes, really long."></a></li>
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#4" data-slide="4"><img src="assets/images/slider4.jpg" alt="And this is some very long caption for slide 4."></a></li>
         <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#1" data-slide="5"><img src="assets/images/slider1.jpg" alt="This is caption 1 <a href='#link'>Even with links!</a>"></a></li>
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#2" data-slide="6"><img src="assets/images/slider1.jpg"  alt="This is caption 2"></a></li>
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#3" data-slide="7"><img src="assets/images/slider1.jpg" alt="And this is some very long caption for slide 3. Yes, really long."></a></li>
        <li class='thmb_li'><a href="#4" data-slide="8"><img src="assets/images/slider4.jpg" alt="And this is some very long caption for slide 4."></a></li>  
        </ul>
        </div>    
   </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Main.js FILE CODE IS HERE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var thumbs = jQuery('#thumbnails').slippry({
  // general elements & wrapper
  slippryWrapper: '<div class="slippry_box thumbnails" />',
  // options
  transition: 'horizontal',
  pager: false,
  auto: false,
  onSlideBefore: function (el, index_old, index_new) {
    jQuery('.for_thmb a img').removeClass('active');
    jQuery('img', jQuery('.for_thmb li')[index_new]).addClass('active');
  }
})

jQuery('.for_thmb a').click(function () {
    alert('ss');
  thumbs.goToSlide($(this).data('slide'));
  return false;
})

$('.easyPaginateNav a').text('');    


$(function() {
$('.thumbs').easyPaginate({
    paginateElement: 'li',
    elementsPerPage: 4,
    effect: 'climb',
    slideOffset: '100',
    firstButton: false,
    lastButton: false,
    prevButton: false,
    nextButton: false
})

});  
});
```

I've also tried changing sequence of scripts which are loaded in the header/footer. I've also changed classes names of divs. As you can see both plugins are using same div.Little help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: maybe this link can help you: https://github.com/aFarkas/jMediaelement/issues/17

Comment: No this is different. Although thanks for trying to help :)